# How can I declare `new () => T` type for a class with protected constructor in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have below code. The `createInstance` will create an instance of `TestOne`. It is done by its parameter `new () => T`. It indicates that the type `T` has a public constructor. However, it doesn't work if I change the `TestOne` constructor to `protected`. Is there a way for me to make the protected constructor work?

```
class TestOne {
    protected constructor(){}
    hi() {
        alert('Hi');
    }
}

function createInstance<T>(type: new () => T){
    return new type();
}


var test = createInstance<TestOne>(TestOne);

var example = test.hi();
```

Comment: If you don't want a protected constructor, don't mark the constructor protected.

Comment: I do want a protected constructor

Comment: Then you can't have a function that instantiates the class.

Comment: Why do you want to have the constructor protected? What's your reasoning?

Comment: I am planning to only allow uses create instance via a static method. There are a few classes implements a same interface. And all of them have protected constructor method.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66599065 for a similar case with an answer