# Typescript Abstract static factory with protected constructor

Tags: typescript, class, abstract

I'm trying to make the following thing,

```
import { IValueObject } from "../../shared/domain/IValueObject";
import { AbstractNanoidGenerator } from "../../shared/infrastructure/AbstractNanoidGenerator";

export class CompanyID extends AbstractNanoidGenerator implements IValueObject<string, CompanyID> {
  protected constructor(private companyID: string) {
    super();
  }

  get value(): string {
    return this.companyID;
  }

  equals(vo: CompanyID) {
    return vo.companyID === this.companyID;
  }
}
```

```
export abstract class AbstractNanoidGenerator {
  static generate<T extends AbstractNanoidGenerator>(this: new (ID: string) => T): T {
    return new this(nanoid());
  }

  static fromString<T extends AbstractNanoidGenerator>(this: new (ID: string) => T, id: string) {
    return new this(id);
  }
}
```

```
export interface IValueObject<T, FinalClass> {
  readonly value: T;
  equals(_vo: FinalClass): boolean;
}
```

It works, but they ask me to declare the constructor of the child class as public. Which I would not do.

`The 'this' context of type 'typeof CompanyID' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'new (ID: string) => CompanyID'. Cannot assign a 'protected' constructor type to a 'public' constructor type.ts(2684)`

Any idea ?

[Here is the link to the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKApgHgDg9gTgFwAQEMBGBnBcUGNm4A2KGGSAgptnggHIoB2MAlgCYDiYDYOC8SAb1BIkWFAma4kAcy49xYADwAVJJARdWZSlhz56TNp2694APgAUCABbMMALiTcA7kgsBJACKPdzBtIBKJABeMyRlAMdVIRARETgwBABXOAYnMFcbOwsAWXFrADocBlYYAFsLAIK%20AGVsP2lKgIBuYSQAX1A2sQkpADM4crq4BpU1CA0S7So9OkYWDjlTOEssh3TXD29Rev8g0PCAGiQ2H13AwTb4xJS0lyQ1izYWts6QN9BIWEQThg04Pp4MBIdwANRQhCSYAA8mgAFZgfAqY4AMT8EIAwsRSGEYtcUKUGIQAJ5IABuEKhUVasTUAEckhCMBYAPpkmCONEMTHYjCRJBoGAwQhgRg0j7gaDwAi8pAY8pQRjErzjSZaCgzGgGBbGeR8OAnMpQEVlLgIMhgykw%20GIhCKXz%20Y7yo1Kry4tpQQYafBgVhIXAwBi6JL4eAWT3MCkaf0K13bB0XPFxDBJKA8So0kQSkSyZAUyFgSpnEb%20S6067JVIPWwYAoBl0MZWeTMdLq0sAMpkWdmOZ2KxteIJJiu3ckwOuxgeeELBYLVuwThtNltvCUAejXMdYYDbAaDyDYITlk6bBVkJgUlSAA)

Regards

Comment: Please share  IValueObject

Comment: Try this example https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgagQwDYFcIHkBGArCBjYAHgBUAaKAVQD4oBeKAbwFgAoKdqBALijNY6iYeFVgF9WrCAA8wAewBOwTpgDOweQgJQ8SBCpVQAogDtgAS1CEYAEWLho04BGMATA-GRosuAoTXyzYwBzchs7SCoaZjYOMHlZJwIIF21ZY38UAgUACjizADcEJyhAp3ljZBseMPsASkYocRZ+WJRMJDM8KCCIJTMXbProgQF5XpRyqGAACzMVADpSiHLK6wBuFvYmptYgA 
and let me know if it works for you

Comment: @captain-yossarian Sorry dude, I've changed the code a bit, I was sharing the wrong example. Let's check the edited post

Comment: I don't have any error :( could you please share it in TS playground?

Comment: @captain-yossarian Done, in the post directly, keep me in touch :-) Thanks

Answer (score 4):

## The Problem

`protected` is an access modifier. You cannot put it on a type or **interface**, since they are [**public** contracts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37792536).  So, we won't be able to specify protected properties on a **type** that's going to be used when defining parameters of a function, including `this`.

In our case, when we say `this: new (ID: string) => T`, we are saying the passed argument for `this` (or technically, the "context object" that this function is called on), should be of type `new (ID: string) => T`.  Which only stands for **public** properties. :(

As of November 2021 (TS 4.5), there still isn't any way to talk about `protected` properties of an interface (see [this comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25163#issuecomment-433643933)), and/or specifying `protected` constructors of a class.

TS 4.2 [has add support](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#abstract-construct-signatures) for `abstract` Construct Signatures. So, hopefully in the future we might see some support for the protected constructors, as well.

## The Hack

We learned that you cannot enforce that the passed `this` parameter to have a protected constructor.  What's the next best alternative, that's better than `any`? :)

Let's say we are good with assuming that if it's a subclass of `AbstractNanoidGenerator`, it's always going to have a protected constructor that takes an `(ID: string)` and returns an instance of itself. (same subclass.)

So our mission would be just enforcing the `this` param to be "a subclass of `AbstractNanoidGenerator`" and properly determine the return type to be an instance of that subtype.

### Class vs Instance Object

First of all, let's review the difference between the "Class" and "Instance Object"s.

When you say `let id: CompanyID`, the type of `id` is **An instance of** the CompanyID class.

But the `this` in the static functions above is not supposed to be `this: CompanyID` which would imply we need an instance!  We want the actual `CompanyID` class itself to be passed/used, which has the type of `typeof CompanyID` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56939536)). :)

### How should we say we want the class itself?

There are two main ways in TypeScript to have the type for a "Class".  That would be used to enforce the `this` parameter in our case.

#### Class Type Version 1: Using `new`

The most common way to imply something is a "Class" is to say if you call `new` on that, it's gonna produce an "Instance". That inspires ([this type of solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52183279)) to go with the following utility functions.

```
export interface Type<T> extends Function {
    new (...args: any[]): T;
}

// --- Or, similarly ---
export type Constructor<VALUE_T = any> = new (...args: any[]) => VALUE_T;
```

#### Class Type Version 2: Using `prototype`

The problem with the above version is that it doesn't work for classes with protected constructor, like our `CompanyID`.  Such classes don't have a public constructor to be picked up by `new`, and will fail there.

That's why in our second way we rely on having a property called `prototype`.

```
export type ClassDefinitionFor<T> = { prototype: T };
```

(So, `let theClass:ClassDefinitionFor<CompanyID> = CompanyID` works!)

and to reverse that...

```
type InstanceOfClass<T> = T extends { prototype: infer R } ? R : never;
```

### What should be the params now?

Given the two utility functions above, I wrote the following.

Note that using `as unknown as` trick, we are telling TS to consider that just because `this` is a Class object that extends `AbstractNanoidGenerator`, it has a constructor that produces an object, with the type on the `prototype` of that class.

```
type ClassDefinitionFor<T>  = { prototype: T };
type InstanceOfClass<T>     = T extends { prototype: infer R } ? R : never;

export abstract class AbstractNanoidGenerator {
  static generate<
    INSTANCE_T extends AbstractNanoidGenerator,
    CLASS_T extends ClassDefinitionFor<INSTANCE_T>,
    CTR_T extends new (ID: string) => InstanceOfClass<CLASS_T>,
  >(this: CLASS_T): InstanceOfClass<CLASS_T> {
    return new (this as unknown as CTR_T)(Math.random().toString());
  }
}
```

([Full TS Playground with extra tests](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgNgQwM5ICIQGYEsB2XhYD2OAYoQE4A8AKgHxRQC8UA3lGOYcF%20BAFxRqUAL4BuALAAoUJCgBJHEmAIcAYwgB5DPGRIa9Bg2ZCIAD2AQcAEySt2nbjP5RcGCOSgAlEVAD8XqAEcCAA3dwlJKTMwCmAoBAAjJXIEVTjVRBQoAEEk4BS0gDkVQiwrAHFLdwRuDxYpBiUarFUoAHMqlItKBsM5QoBlamzCmABRAH0Tc0sbHLyC4GKcUorOmooAGl6GGAAZbIGBqagzC2tbHRR0bDwCYjIqfqGR8anabclDWGpPE7PZrZggB3KAACjkqAEyVwbQAlEx6AommpNNpMnp9odjnRPgxaGDgAALLBIARYo5TOECZHKVFaK6Yg6UuisHZQcgQYAAV3IOCgIPBxNJ8Vs3JwAGsVsD%20cgfn9qHCwQBZGpEgB0KWshAAtmC4eruAN8rD9XCIgxhFJek0CK0MJwdcbyLCaKcZhd5slUksSmVKsEuhQCcKyQKIKCIVCoDCcPDEYJNi4rNCTXGEfUvoZOTy%20eHQaGwWVzb0rZIy1FTDFyHFcBZyBhUtA5AA1BBwbmaBIAKwgaRoSZIuHbjPomYYnIQVmIcBAUBC7c7AmoFtOAEdue2kGCJiFCAIhzgRxjqVAEoRCHAICoIhXJNFYlAMrpYLqwCoQJD3ec5rlvUU-TWQMNg8LAdTAK8dUsYBbFbRcu17ftYzaJMYDfD9ITHXoOC4PsLCsJ9iGSbk0goMEOCwBcLEI8CMOjZCM3ZJBuUgch9VXO8GA6OIFw7CB9VTF04zZLMJy5Xl%20VDdVVHQnBP1QDjrSzCANy3ME93JWT5MY0SOXEvM92krSv0YUyoCkmTaLkyFFPLJSAHp7MIqwICkK84mJCBGT4RkblwfAiFIChKDQqz5PoZhQvfayFKkJxzIAJiYeRFDpdQGQxSgnEIDBXzCzCIikGTUuTZKoro9UOmAix9SgRzBCJaB4pFcqYqKojLwgdU4EINoiysdUVM3OBt2Lc1vjqpz1Wm8zCCgHUEAlaBmM5dp1hqhFCG5YAwG2y5jNQJMVAIlY4j-fIfWWVYA2qWolOKpRkyS5hBVa%20SwQAIgAVi%20j6EXq5VuUehJoHcThyAEQo5t2hI4BaQjUvIEi7skB7aysABmZKykq9b%20IRCbJqgQHgdB8hwYEXHqvxmMiS2uACJnOdlCWlxJMa2AMT8u5AqkIA).)